# How come the span tag is being pushed down?

Tags: css

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height:300px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#container {
  width: 50%;
  height:100%;
  border: 15px solid orange; 
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#firstDiv{
  border: 10px solid brown;     
  width: 50%;
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.person_status{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="firstDiv">
    <span class="person_name">peter</span>
    <span class="person_status">something</span>
  </div>
  <div id="firstDiv">
    <span class="person_name">peter</span>
    <span class="person_status">something</span>
  </div>
  <div id="firstDiv">
    <span class="person_name">peter</span>
    <span class="person_status">something</span>
  </div>
  <div id="firstDiv">
    <span class="person_name">peter</span>
    <span class="person_status">something</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a demo of my problem.
Does anyone know how to handle this?

I've tried to align top, but it doesn't work. And also, in Firefox, the scrollbar dissapears when I add:  `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: Please add the code in the question, and not just a link. This time I have edited it, but the next time your question may be closed.

Comment: What do you want to do with these span tags? .. Span tags are "inline" elements, which respond different from "block" elements.

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left` to the `.person_name` elements.

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height:300px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#container {
  width: 50%;
  height:100%;
  border: 15px solid orange; 
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#firstDiv{
  border: 10px solid brown;     
  width: 50%;
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.person_name{
  float:left;
}
.person_status{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="firstDiv">
    <span class="person_name">peter</span>
    <span class="person_status">something</span>
  </div>
  <div id="firstDiv">
    <span class="person_name">peter</span>
    <span class="person_status">something</span>
  </div>
  <div id="firstDiv">
    <span class="person_name">peter</span>
    <span class="person_status">something</span>
  </div>
  <div id="firstDiv">
    <span class="person_name">peter</span>
    <span class="person_status">something</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver. Thank you very much. And sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: It would be great to know why, though. I can't see where the spec says that `white-space: nowrap` prevents having floats in the same line as some inline content.